# Using Bootbox Confirm, where to place preventDefault?

Tags: jquery, bootbox

I have a basic web page, MVC with jQuery and Bootbox, when the user clicks on a delete link I would like to display a confirmation box, yes -or- no and then preventDefault or return false based on the answer. Pretty simple stuff but I can't seem to capture the result value from BootBox.

The HTML snippet

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserDetailId }, 
                                                     new { @class = "delete_click", onclick = "return ConfirmDelete('" + item.Email + "');" })
```

The Javascript

```js
var confirm_result = false;

function ConfirmDelete(message) {
  bootbox.confirm({
    message: "<h3>Delete this account:</h3> <span class=bold> " + message + " </span>",
    buttons: {
      cancel: {
        label: 'No'
      },
      confirm: {
        label: 'Yes'
      }
    },
    callback: function(result) {
      console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
      confirm_result = result;
    }
  });
  // ?? how do I control the true/false return value here ??
  return false;
};
```

Everything works, no errors, dialog is displayed, callback is called, etc; but the confirm_result does not get set to true when the user clicks OK?

Do I need to split the callback to a separate function?

**UPDATE**: The callback is asynchronous! The ConfirmDelete function always exits before the callback has been executed! That's my problem, working on a fix ....

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten how this works, the OnClick function calls the BootBox dialog which displays and **then** immediately exits. I return 'false' from the ConfirmDelete function to prevent the link from working. To submit the delete when the user clicks OK, I needed to redirect from inside the callback. The 'better' code looks like this.

```
    function ConfirmDelete(name, id) {
        bootbox.confirm({
            message: "Delete this user: " + name + "?",
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: 'Yes'
                },
                cancel: {
                    label: 'No'
                }
            },
            callback: function (result) {
                if (result)
                {
                    var url = "Delete/" + id;
                    console.log("redirect to url:" + url);
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
                else
                { console.log("cancel delete"); }
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
```

Note the window.location.href call, that was the key. There are other issues with managing a web page like this, managing the back button, etc; but this is working as expected.

AJAX is your friend, learn to use AJAX!